# redirect to different location based on $uri in nginx

Tags: nginx

I would like to redirect to different page if there is request params present:

```
http://domain.com  --> index.html

http://domain.com/1 --> return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

current config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    location / {
      #return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   }
}
```

How can I redirect to locations based on uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
...
location = / {
       return 301 http://$host/index.html
}

location ~ ^/1 {
       return 301 https://$host/$1
}
...
```